# how to get all enum field in a column side by side seperated by comma (,) in a mysql by query

Tags: mysql

In mysql i need to get enum fields side by side in a column when i run a query with group by , just like as follows.

There is table as like below

```
mysql> describe tabex;
+---------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)                    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| personid| int(11)                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| color   | enum('red','blue','white') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

there are different shirts , the column personid describes the that person id and color indicates the color of his shirt..

the data in table is as follows

```
mysql> select * from tabex;
+----+----------+-------+
| id | personid | color |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | red   |
|  2 |        1 | white |
|  3 |        2 | blue  |
|  4 |        2 | red   |
+----+----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when i ran a query i am getting results like this

```
mysql> select personid , color from tabex group by personid;
+----------+-------+
| personid | color |
+----------+-------+
|        1 | red   |
|        2 | blue  |
+----------+-------+
```

but i want the result like below

```
+----------+-------------+               
|personid  |   color     |               
+----------+-------------+               
|1         |   red,white |               
|2         |   blue,red  |               
|          |             |               
+----------+-------------+
```

how can i get the result as above by using group by and aggregation (if any for enum).

that is here i want to get the result for enum fields as like we will get by using count or sum functions and group by .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function does what you want:

```
SELECT personid, GROUP_CONCAT(color) colors
FROM tabex
GROUP BY personid
```

This works with any kind of field, not just ENUM.